# Proof on if the limit exists for a funtion

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let D = (0, 2){1}, and define f : D -> R by f(x) = (-x^3 + x^2 + 4x - 4)/(x-1). Show using, the definition, that f has a limit at x = 1.

My proof: 
Let e > 0. 
We claim that lim x-> 1 f(x) = 3.
We will find d such that |x-1| < d => |f(x) - 3| < e. 
We see that |f(x) - 3| = |(x+1)(x-1)|. 
We see that|x+1| <= 3, as x is in D.
So, choose delta = e/3, so that |x-1| < e/3.
It follows that |f(x) - 3|<= 3|x-1| < e.
Thus, by the definition of a functional limit, f(x) has a limit at x = 1.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

$$|f(x)-3|=|x+1| |x-1|$$
$x$ is near $1 $, so we can add the assumption $ 0<x<2 $ or
$$1<|x+1|<3$$

thus if $|x-1|<1$ then
$$|f(x)-3|<3|x-1|$$
thus,

to realise the condition $|f(x)-3|<e $ for given $e>0$, it is sufficient to have

$$\Bigl( |x-1|<1 \;\; \text{ and }\;\; 3|x-1|<e \Bigr)$$
or

$$|x-1|<\min(1,\frac e3)$$
finally, you will take
$\delta=\min(1,\frac e3)$